# Magento 2: Manual Import Image Issue

Tags: magento2, import, image, product-images, custom

Admin Import Has Issue:

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/6939

I'm able to Manually Add Product.

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/140234/magento-2-after-entry-in-database-tables-unable-to-save-new-entry-record-solv

For Images, i'm checking previous uploaded Product's Images & following.

I have put my new image in `pub\media\catalog\product\a\b\abc.png`

Made respective entry in below tables

```
catalog_product_entity_varchar
catalog_product_entity_media_gallery
catalog_product_flat_1 -> Updated fields image, small_image, swatch_image, thumbnail
```

Frontend: Images are displaying on Listing Pages. **On Product Detail page it's not Showing Image.**

Admin: On Catalog listing it's displaying, **while edit product it's not Showing Image.**

**What if i have same image name, But Image is different for Different Product.**

As path is `pub\media\catalog\product\a\b\abc.png` it will override Image?

If this is not going to work i have do edit 2K SKU manually & upload Images. Crazy

Answer (score -1):

Why not use the native product image import for Magento 2 ?

You can check the official documentation here :

- http://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/system/data-import-product-images.html